# Counting the number of unique sets in a list

Tags: python

If you have a list of sets like this:

```
a_list = [{'a'}, {'a'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}]
```

How could one get the number of unique sets in the list?

I have tried:

```
len(set(a_list ))
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Desired output in this case is: 3 as there are three unique sets in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `tuple`:

```
a_list = [{'a'}, {'a'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}]
result = list(map(set, set(map(tuple, a_list))))
print(len(result))
```

Output:

```
[{'a', 'b'}, {'a'}, {'c', 'a', 'b'}]
3
```

A less functional approach, perhaps a bit more readable:

```
result = [set(c) for c in set([tuple(i) for i in a_list])]
```

Comment: Wohooo! that was fast

Comment: OP might also want to consider frozensets in case `{a, b}` should be considered the same as `{b, a}`.... eg: `list({frozenset(el) for el in a_list}) `

Comment: I agree with Jon here. This doesn't seem right to me - are `tuple` of `{'a', 'b'}` and `{'b','a'}` guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: However, seems what the OP's likely after is `len({frozenset(el) for el in a_list})`...

Answer (score 1):

How about Converting to a tuple:

```
a_list = [{'a'}, {'a'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}]

print(len(set(map(tuple, a_list))))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
3
```